# Strange switch-statement behavior

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

Can someone show me why this `switch` statement doesn't output the same as the `if` statement?
And more important, how do I get them to output the same?

**Switch**

```
switch ($list_day) { 
        case $today : 
            $calender .= '<td class="today">';
        default : 
            $calender .= '<td>';
    }
```

**If**

```
if ($list_day == $today) {
        $calendar.= '<td class="today">';
    } else {
        $calendar.= '<td>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
switch ($list_day) { 
    case $today : 
        $calendar .= '<td class="today">';
        break;
    default : 
        $calendar .= '<td>';
}
```

As well as the break i previously submitted, you typed $calender instead of $calendar...

Comment: Perhaps this should be merged into your original answer?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing your `break` statements:

```
switch ($list_day) { 
        case $today : 
            $calender .= '<td class="today">';
            break;
        default : 
            $calender .= '<td>';
    }
```

If you don't break out of the switch statement execution just continues with the next label. This allows you to chain labels together:

```
switch($number) {
case 1: case 2: case 3:
  echo '1 - 3';
  break;
case 4:
  echo '4';
  break;
default
  echo 'any other number';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still show me a different output then the if-statement

Comment: @Michiel: It shouldn't … What's the exact output you're getting and what is the expected output? Values for your variables, or any errors?

Comment: Although good work, i found the real answer, look at my second post :P

Comment: You spelled calendar two different ways, one correct and one not :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot your BREAK;

In Pascal style code such as pascal, visual basic, you don't need to BREAK on each case. But in C-Style/Java/PHP/etc you need:

```
switch ($list_day) { 
    case $today : 
        $calender .= '<td class="today">';
        break;
    default : 
        $calender .= '<td>';
}
```

This can be used to do some fancy things that i'll let you figure out yourself!

Comment: Thanks, but it still show me a different output then the if-statement